# Lie algebra cohomology of the space of vector fields

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, ra.rings-and-algebras, riemannian-geometry, noncommutative-geometry, lie-algebra-cohomology

For a (closed and oriented) manifold $M$, the first Lie algebra cohomology $H^1(\mathrm{Vect}(M),C^\infty(M))$ of the space of vector fields with coefficients in smooth functions is isomorphic to $H^1(M,\mathbb{R})\oplus\mathbb{R}\operatorname{div}$, where $\operatorname{div}$ is the divergence associated with an arbitrary volume form. (For the reference, see Theorem 2.4.11 of "Cohomology of Infinite-dimensional Lie Algebras" by D. B. Fuks.)

**Question:** Are there any analogues in non-commutative geometry? For example, is $H^1(\operatorname{Der}(A),A/[A,A])$ isomorphic to $\mathrm{HDR}^1(A)\oplus K$ for a unital associative $K$-algebra $A$ with $\mathrm{HDR}^0(A)=K$?

Here $\mathrm{HDR}^1$ is the Karoubi-de Rham cohomology of $A$. I suppose some kind of smoothness or finite-dimensionality would be required.

Thank you.

Comment: It's not true for $A=\{0\}$, since the left-hand term is zero and the right-hand term is not (because of $\oplus K$). You might also compare with the case of $M$ with $n$ connected components, which corresponds to $A$ being a product of $n$ indecomposable commutative algebras.

Comment: @YCor Thanks for the comment. Some assumptions are added.